# Custom cursor in C# Winforms

Tags: c#, visual-studio, mouse-cursor

Does anyone know of an easy way to use a custom cursor? I have both a .cur and .png of my cursor.  I tried adding it as a resource to my project and also tried including it as a file in the project.  Ideally I'd like to embed it but I just want to get it working.

When I use `Cursor cur = new Cursor("mycursor.cur")` I get "Image format is not valid. The image file may be corrupted".  I tried this http://mahesg.wordpress.com/2008/02/09/embedding-cursor/ but it didn't work.  Using `WinForm1.Properties.Resources.mycursor` returns a byte[] which I have no idea how to convert into a Cursor type.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For some reason the cursor class is far too picky about what it will read. You can create the handle yourself using the windows API then pass that to the cursor class.

C#:

```
//(in a class)
public static Cursor ActuallyLoadCursor(String path) {
    return new Cursor(LoadCursorFromFile(path))
}
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern IntPtr LoadCursorFromFile(string fileName);
```

VB.Net:

```
'(in a class)'
Public Shared Function ActuallyLoadCursor(path As String) As Cursor
    Return New Cursor(LoadCursorFromFile(path))
End Function
<System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")>
Private Shared Function LoadCursorFromFile(fileName As String) As IntPtr
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you so effin much @Strilanc, this has been bugging me for ages. I can now finish my dissertation project!! :D

Comment: This worked great in 2022. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Write `new Cursor(new MemoryStream(Properties.Resources.mycursor))`

Comment: Tried that, still didn't change anything.

Comment: Make sure it's actually a `.cur` file, which is different from any other image format.

Comment: I think there may be something wrong with the .cur file.  I saved it in Photoshop which gave me an option for .cur so I assumed it was a valid .cur file. Must've been an outdated plugin.  The cursor works using the PNG but not the CUR.  Does it make a difference?

Comment: That's suprising.  What happens if you select it in Mouse Properties?

Comment: Although cursor image is changed. But cursor can't click according to its size. Its click radar as same as previous.

Answer (score 4):

### Adding custom icon to cursor in C# :

Add Icon file to Project resources (ex : Processing.ico)

And in properties window of image switch "Build Action" to "Embedded"

```
Cursor cur = new Cursor(Properties.Resources.**Imagename**.Handle);
this.Cursor = cur;
```

Ex:

```
Cursor cur = new Cursor(Properties.Resources.Processing.Handle);
this.Cursor = cur;
```

Comment: *"Add Icon file to Project resources"*  How is that done?  Dragging and dropping the cursor file on to the project's `Resources.resx` in the Solution Explorer?

Comment: "Add Icon file to Project resources" How is that done? Dragging and dropping the cursor file on to the project's Resources.resx in the Solution Explorer? How? Please don't be vague or double ended in your answers.

Comment: "Add Icon file to project resources" means to open Project properties -> Ressources  -> "Add ressource" -> "Add exisitng file"

Answer (score 0):

Objective: To change cursor to a custom cursor when user need to do cut activity in a sample winforms UI

Do this it will work

1. Add the icon file (e.g cut.ico) to the project
2. Now add icon to project resource
   To add to resource right click on project->properties->Resources Now drop the ico file from the project folder (U added to project folder in point 1) on Resources
3. This code should do the trick

```cs
System.Windows.Forms.Cursor _customCutCursor = 
   new System.Windows.Forms.Cursor(Properties.Resources.cut.Handle);
```