# Changing mouse pointer on hover

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am trying to change the mouse pointer to a `.png` image on mouse hover over a panel, but didn't achieve success as yet. Any suggestions?

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
Cursor myCursor = new Cursor("pic1.png");
myControl.Cursor = myCursor;
```

Comment: Here you find your answer. [Custom Cursor][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6638720/custom-cursor-in-c-sharp-winforms

Answer (score 3):

You need to make the image, a .cur file and then add the cursor file as a project resource.

Follow this step:

1. Goto `Project Properties->Resource` tab.
2. Click arrow on the **"Add Resource"** button, and add your **.cur** file

In your code you can use it like:

```
Dim memstrm As New System.IO.MemoryStream(My.Resources.CustomCursor)
YourButton.Cursor = New Cursor(memstrm)
```